# Download file using android-async-loopj

Tags: android, android-async-http

I am using this code:

```
/* This is an asynchronusHTTP client*/
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, params,new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(file) {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
           // Do something with the file `response`
        }
});
```

but I got the file which is empty. Documentation says on success it writes result to the file passed but that is not happening.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you saying that it works if you put in the URL into a browser it works, but not in your code?
What does your log show as your `url` that you use in `client.get()` ?

Comment: I am getting a url from a server where it converts "\"" and " " to some number due to which it is gives me Illegal character error.

Comment: have you solved this

Comment: yes, this is solved as i said in my earlier comment

Answer (score 0):

What your are saying is called URL Encoding which will not give illegal character error as for as I know.. If you think that URL Encoding is the problem the try add this line in your get(String url, RequestParams params,FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)) function.

```
client.setURLEncodingEnabled(false);
```